# Content from ajax call not always loading

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've created a control panel from which the administrator of the website can change the content of a booking form (he can change the options tags of a select).

To retrive the content, once the index.html (home page) get called the file getItinerary.js should populate the select with the options tag.

getItinerary.js contains an ajax call, here is the code:

**getItinerari.js**

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"private/getItinerari.php"
}).done(function(itinerario_out){
    //console.log(itinerario_out);
    var route = JSON.parse(itinerario_out);
    for(var i in route){
        $('#basic').append('<option id="'+ route[i].it_id +'" value="'+route[i].it_id +'">'+ route[i].itinerario +'</option>');
    }

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"private/getSortable.php",
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (list) {
        var sortedList = list;

        sortedList.forEach(function(id) {
            $("#" + id).appendTo("#basic")
        })
    })
});
```

and I include this JS file at the bottom of my home page like this

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/getItinerari.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <!--[if IE]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/placeholder_ie.js"></script>     
        <![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom-form-elements.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.selectbox-0.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.blueberry.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script src="js/calculatePrice.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="js/routeprice.js"></script>-->

        <!-- Validate forms-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/validate.js"></script>
    </body>
```

The problem is that the content is not always loaded...if I refresh the page by pressing ctrl + f5 most of the time i can se the content...otherwise the select is empty...any idea why?

Comment: Is it possible that you're using a particular library to display the select boxes? For some of them, they won't automatically show the new results if you modify the DOM under them, but rather than that, they will need you to call something for them to refresh. If you do, take them out and check if you still have the same problem.

Comment: You are right...the problem is caused by jquery.selectbox-0.2.min.js...any idea hot to make this work?

Comment: Check their API: https://github.com/marcj/jquery-selectBox -- they seem to have a refresh option you can pass. You would probably be calling `selectBox` again on it. Once you figure it out, feel free to post it as an answer, so others can benefit from it! :)

Comment: try a `$(document).ready(function(){ /**... your code here ... **/ })` wrapper to ge sure all dom elements are completely rendered